# With the Pixel line, Google has abandoned Android Open Accessory 2.0. What do they use for USB audio now?

Tags: audio, moto-x, android-open-accessory

I recently got a Moto X4. Unlike my previous phone, the Nexus 5X, this one does not support [AOA 2.0](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol), meaning it cannot digitally connect to the Kenwood head unit in my car. Previously, I was able to broadcast sound from my phone to the car stereo, and could use the pause and navigation buttons to control my phone. No more.

I emailed Project Fi about it, and while they couldn't tell me for sure whether the X4 could do this (it can't), they did tell me that the Pixel phones do not support AOA.

So, if Google doesn't support AOA on their phones anymore, is there any new protocol or API to replace it? Has Google given up on USB audio? Or are there USB headphones you can connect directly to the Pixel? For car stereos, is Android Auto support the only way to go from here on out?